# Saving a copy of text file by matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to make a copy of a text file in a folder by using matlab.

For instance, 
If there is a function like `saveCopy(original file name, new file name, directory)`,  we could make a copied file, abc2.bdf file, from original file, abc1.bdf file.

Would it be any ways to do like the example?

Comment: Have a look at [copyfile](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html). Especially with the syntax `copyfile('myFun.m','myFun2.m')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [copyfile](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html)

```
copyfile('oldname', fullfile(directory, 'newname'))
```

The function, [fullfile](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) builds the file path.